Problem calculating surface integral over a cylinder
Problem: Find the surface integral $I=\iint_S2x^2ydydz-y^2dzdx+4xz^2dxdy$, where $S$ is curved surface of the cylinder $y^2+z^2=9$ bounded by the planes $x=0,\,x=2$.
I wasn't familiar with this representation, so I checked on MSE and came around this post, in which the OP used Jacobians. Using cylindrical coordinates for the surface with $x=x$, $y=3\cos\theta$, and $z=3\sin\theta$, I got
$$ dydz = 0dxd\theta\\dzdx=-3\cos\theta dxd\theta\\dxdy=-3\sin\theta dxd\theta$$
Replacing, I got $$I=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2 27\cos^3\theta-12x\sin^3\theta dxd\theta=0$$
The answer says $180$. What am I doing wrong?
Edit: An issue I noticed with this method is the sign of the Jacobians switch if I change the order of integration. So, I'm not confident about this method. Is there a more appropriate way to solve surface integrals of this form?

That zero in the first differential equation looks wrong to me.

@Daniel why? $y$ and $z$ do not depend on $x$

@Daniel that's what made me a bit sus too. but hey, I've tried like 3 methods so far, all giving me 0 at the end

I tried to make sense of the $dydz$ being 0 as - they are proportional to $d\theta^2$. dunno if that even works

@Laxmi what is the source of this problem?

@sine I don't know what our teacher uses as the source for problems, so yeah, can't say much. I did find a solution page for this in chegg, but that needs money, so I have no idea if the given answer is right.

Late reply, but the first part of the big integral looks wrong; I think either dy or dz needs to be dx. As it is now, after integrating with respect to y and z you are left with a function of x^2

@Daniel Check the post I had mentioned. As I explained in the post, this is one of the representations of surface integral, based on wedge products afaik. It's like the line integral $$\int_C Pdx+Qdy$$
